# How to set angular moment timezone globally?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, timezone, momentjs

I used angular moment js on my angular app. I want to show date and time according to the time zone of the current user. I'm unable to apply time zone globally on my app.

https://github.com/urish/angular-moment

I tried this.

```
angular.module('myapp').constant('angularMomentConfig', {
    timezone: 'Europe/London' // e.g. 'Europe/London'
});
```

In one of my view -

```
{{home.eventStart| amDateFormat:'dddd, MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a'}}
```

In one of my controller -

```
$scope.profile.eventStart = moment(data.start).format('YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm a');
```

I'm not getting any changes in both cases, even after I set the time zone. Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 4):

You cannot change constant after you set it. As injections are not dependent on module.constant or module value, this should do the trick:

```
angular.module('myapp').value('angularMomentConfig', {
    timezone: 'Europe/London' // e.g. 'Europe/London'
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The `timezone` parameter is optional.  If you omit it, it will use the time zone of the local machine automatically.  That is the default behavior of moment.js and of the JavaScript `Date` object.

Answer (score 1):

I too had the same problem.

This is how to solve this out.

You need to include [moment-timezone.js](http://momentjs.com/timezone/) v0.3.0 or greater in your project, otherwise the custom timezone functionality will not be available.

[Documentation here](https://github.com/urish/angular-moment#time-zone-support)

Answer (score 1):

Since version 1.0.0-beta.1, time zone can be set using **amMoment** service. Just inject the amMoment service and call changeTimeZone:

```
amMoment.changeTimezone('Europe/London');
```

Answer (score -2):

```
app.run(['amMoment',
    function (amMoment) {
        amMoment.changeTimezone('Europe/Paris');
    }
]);
```

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this". We make an effort here to be a resource for knowledge.